Least squares rational approximation to $\arcsin x + \sqrt{1-x^2}$ in form $[3,1]$
I'm trying to generate a decent $[3,1]$ rational least squares polynomial approximation to $\arcsin(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and failing dismally :(
The problem is that for this particular combination of $N,D$ and a handful of others (approx. $11\%$), those I tested rational approximations to this function go completely haywire. This is the first step in a Remez equal ripple code.
I have ported the original ARM Julia Remez code, which works in arbitrary precision (so numerical instability can be ruled out) to C, and get about the same results as the Julia code for modest $N,D$. I still find debugging easier in C/C++. The algebra all looks fine to me, and it works OK in $\approx 89\%$ of cases for $N, D \leq 20$. It uses a trick described here $\arcsin$ when fast sqrt available. This is of interest again because hardware sqrt is now so fast.
Unfortunately, the equation is rather fickle and rational Remez solutions to it are a bit thin on the ground. When the original author tried it, he listed all the solutions that were soluble in Maple/Mathematica with $\text{digits} = 30$ for N, D <= 20 at the end. My improvements have got past some of those obstacles. I expect Maple & Mathematica have also improved in the meantime too. I'm using it as an awkward test case for the least squares fitting code.
The remaining failing cases in Julia implementation are (my C code can duplicate them up to $N+D \approx 9$):



D
Fails
Failing N values




0
0



1
1
3


2
1
6


3
1
9


4
3
4   12  14


5
3
1   7   17


6
2
10  20


7
2
1   13


8
3
8   16  18


9
2
5   11


10
2
2   14


11
1
17


12
4
2   6   12  20


13
2
9   15


14
1
18


15
2
3   7


16
2
10  16


17
4
3   7   13  19


18
0



19
2
11  17


20
4
4   8   14  20



Total failures  42/400

There is a sort of pattern visible in the failures. Notably that the first failures occur in pairs at $N$, $D=5N$ and $D=5N+2$ $[1,5][1,7]$, $[2,10][2,12]$, $[3,15][3,17]$ and the other heuristic is that failing ones tend to be at an offset at $N+1$, $D+3$ or $N+1$, $D+5$ from a previous failing one at $N,D$. I have no idea why this is. I'd be grateful for any mathematical insight as to why they fail. I'm a physicist by training.
I can torment the code further by forcing a fit onto $[-1,1]$, which yields a different pattern of poles and gives rather poor results.
My concrete question is can someone else please try and construct a least squares rational polynomial $[3,1]$ on $[0,1]$ with $6$ extrema that will fit this function and does not have a pole in the denominator or if that isn't possible (and I begin to think that it might not be) suggestions on how else to tame $\arcsin(x)$ as $x \rightarrow 1$.
These are the (truncated coefficients for the various polynomials along the slice $N+D = 4$ to which $[3,1]$ belongs.



N
D
a0
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
min
max
Extrema




4
0
0.999552605
1.012294397
-0.567674648
0.283495466
-0.155816204
1
-0.000486329
0.00105529
LHLHLH


3
1
1.000344626
-0.138900694
-1.51998173
0.463582739
1
-1.123994409
$-\inf$
$+\inf$
HLHLPLH


2
2
0.999908687
0.845226481
-0.950516017
1
-0.158392266
-0.272262394
-0.000360445
0.000515648
LHLHLH


1
3
0.9997
2.270119177
1
1.248325161
-0.536562537
0.368
-0.00098187
0.001411549
LHLHLH


0
4
1.0014
1
-0.959053269
1.152066248
-0.849712791
0.29415
-0.000515845
0.0014
HLHLHLH


3
1
1.000688177
0.08167677
-1.276224508
0.356408177
1
-0.896572376
-0.000709689
0.000820716
HLHLH


3
1
1.000680259
0.082019016
-1.276955723
0.356828838
1
-0.896546345
-0.0006804
+0.0006803
HLHLH



The respective error residuals graphs for each of the approximations above are in my original post on Stack Exchange. The adjusted [3,1] isn't shown but just looks like a W). A correct optimum least squares solution should look like W\ or /W HLHLHL or the opposite.
AOBE I would probably use $[2,2]$ or $[3,2]$ as the best trade-off on simplicity vs accuracy. But $[3,1]$ would be very handy if it exists.
I have tried weighting the fit and various analytic transformations to move the excess coefficient from the denominator into the numerator and obtained a sort of solution at the bottom of the table, but which doesn't oscillate enough to be acceptable for Remez.
My goal is to have $N+D+2$ extrema in the rational approximation $[3,1]$, including the two endpoints. An interesting curiosity is that $[0,4]$ actually has N+D+3 extrema due to serendipity. The other ones giving problems with poles are $[1,5]$, $[1,7]$, $[4,4]$ and $[6,1]$. I have focused on $[3,1]$ specifically because I had hoped that analytic methods on cubic equations might allow me to find a well-behaved solution - if one exists.
I found, empirically, that I could prevent the pole from being in the range of $0$ to $1$ by changing to $\arcsin(x) + \sqrt{1-x^2/k}$ where constant $k = 1.00120925005925$.
If an ideal equal ripple solution to target f(x) with error $e$ and $6$ extrema does exist, we have a couple of algebraic constraints that can be used to decrease the search space or sanity check putative answers. Based on the values taken at the ends of the range x = 0 and x=1.
$$r(x) = \frac{a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3}{1-gx}$$
$$f(0) - r(0) = e = 1 - a$$
$$ a = 1 - e $$
$$f(1) - r(0) = -e = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{a+b+c+d}{1-g},$$
so
$$d = \left(\frac{pi}{2}+e \right)(1-g)-1+e-(b+c).$$
And also to avoid having a pole in the range $[0, 1]$ $g < 1 $.
I'm now looking at tricks from solving the cubic and knowing that a final solution with the right number of extrema in the target range $0-1$ must have a derivative with a numerator with all real roots in the same range. This approach is proving tough. I suspect possibly because no such solution exists (brute force on the remaining free parameters hasn't found one yet, either).
$$\arcsin(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2} - \frac{a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3}{1-gx}.$$
If we compute the $x$ derivative of the residual curve, we get and look for the zeroes:
$$\frac{1-x}{\sqrt(1-x^2)} - \frac{(b + 2cx + 3dx^2)(1-gx)+g(a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3)}{(1-gx)^2}.$$
And also another constraint on the gradients at the end of the range, which must both have the same sign if the solution has an even number of extrema.
$$  f'(0)-r'(0) = 1 - [b + ag] $$
$$\begin{align}
f'(1)-r'(1) & = 0 - [(b + 2c + 3d)(1-g) + g(a + b + c + d)] \\ 
&= -[b + 2c + 3d + g(a + b(1-1) + c(1-2) +d(1-3))] \\
&= - [b + ag + 2c + 3d - g(c + 2d)],
\end{align}$$
yielding an inequality
$$(b+ag) \cdot [(b+ag) + 2c + 3d - g(c+2d)] \geq 0.$$
My reasoning is that if a solution with the requisite number of maxima and equal ripple exists, then the resulting equation for $x$ should have a set of values $a,b,c,d,e,g$, which makes both gradients at the end of the range have the same sign and has $4$ roots in the range $[0 - 1]$. Are there any other tricks I have missed?
I have also tried and failed with a brute force numerical attack and simulated annealing (that gave the last two lines in the table are Least Squares and Remez equal ripple). I suspect that a solution with $6$ extrema for this case $[3,1]$ is impossible, but it is beyond my mathematical ability to prove it.
I'd be grateful for any hints on how to prove that a solution does not exist and any insight into the pattern of failing cases when I sweep the range of $N,D$.
I fear that my question is too specific for here and too abstract for Stack Exchange. Apologies, too, for my flaky MathJax formatting on some of the equations.

Could you clarify what are $N$ and $D$ ? Where is $e$ coming from ? Is it Euler number ? I see somewhere a contradiction between the LSQ idea and solving equation. Is it an LSQ problem with some constraints ?

The classical rational polynomial representation of a function is $P(x)/Q(x)$ with $N, D$ as the number of coefficients to solve for in the numerator and denominator respectively. There is an implicit leading 1 in the denominator to anchor the solution. $e$ is the error. Solving for $P(x)$ is trivial but solving for both $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ requires making some dodgy approximations that are evidently not always valid. [3,1] is the simplest hard fail case and I hope may be amenable to analytic techniques although so far I have failed to make any progress proving that it is impossible to solve.

@ClaudeLeibovici Sorry I forgot to tag you with my first reply. I'm really trying to figure out if there is a perfect least squares solution for the case $N=3, D=1$ ie of the form $(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)/(1-gx)$ with maximum error $e$ for the target function $\arcsin x + \sqrt(1-x^2)$. Proving it impossible would be just as good a result for me as finding a solution. So far I can do neither. A brute force search is still running. If there is an ideal 6 extrema solution it is in a tiny isolated zone of the parameter space. The usual Lsq solving method has a nasty pole at ~0.89 and is useless.

Thanks for the clarifications. By the way, the $[3,1]$ Padé approximant is not bad at all (except at $x=-1$)

One more clarification the final target is an equal ripple relative error Remez polynomial fit to the target function. This is just the first step and since it fails the  same way with or without weights on the residuals I chose the simplest failure mode (ie. absolute error).
